# После переноса проекта на новый хостинг перекидывает на страницу установки

Tags: wordpress

Сайт перенес. В `wp-config` все прописал. `.htaccess` так же настроен стандартно.

При переходе по домену кидает на `wp-admin/install.php`

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а базу данных вы перенесли?

Comment: домен сменился же? а в базе его поменяли? Если не меняли ничего, то можно воспользоваться [этим инструментом](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) и заменить старый домен на новый: `wp search-replace --recurse-objects --all-tables-with-prefix OLD_SITE NEW_SITE`. Желательно попрактиковаться где-нибудь на тестовом сервере. Да и вообще этот инструмент удобен для разработки и переноса изменений.

Comment: ох уж эти любители всяких инструментов из командной строки.... http://dimox.name/moving-the-site-on-new-domain/ вот хорошая статья для новичков как это все делается.

Comment: @xaja, первый и третий способы не являются нормальными хотя бы потому, что плагины обновлены не будут. А вот для второго способа и можно использовать ту самую утилитку (этот функционал взят [отсюда](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/))

Comment: все хорошо, но надо у хостера просить ssh?

Comment: Согласен про плагины, я дополняю еще вот так `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://domain.ru', 'http://newdomain.ru');` это покрывает 100% значений в базе

Comment: @xaja, я с хостерами мало работал, а какие видел - везде ssh было. Если же ssh и не будет, можно поставить Search-Replace-DB (ссылка в комменте выше) и воспользоваться им, тогда никаких проблем не будет. Это будет надежнее, чем самому менять запросом в базу: сериализованные данные просто так уже не изменить, а этот инструмент их вроде как корректно обрабатывает (пока проблем не видел)

Comment: дело в том что домен так же перенесен.(какой был такой и остался просто переписал dns) Манипуляции с бд не делал.

wp search-replace 'http://example.dev' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid

wp search-replace 'foo' 'bar' wp_posts wp_postmeta wp_terms --dry-run

# Turn your production database into a local database
wp search-replace --url=example.com example.com example.dev
<- данные действия так понимаю лишние...
Сайт запускается но соль в том что кидает на установку ВП(

Comment: тогда пишите все подробно. Сейчас вордпресс не видит старую базу и пытается создать новую. по тем данным, которые есть в `wp-config` базы он не видит!

Comment: кто-нибудь знает решение этого вопроса? У меня такая же ситуация, не могу разобраться

Comment: Возможно нужно дать права на папку Для того что бы WP мог удалить инсталяционный файл!